# Send metadata with file as a response in Sanic Server Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, sanic

I want to send an audio file, along with some other metadata text (like server details, etc.), as a response in the Sanic server using Python.

I know that we can send, responses in text, JSON, or as a file. But would like to know, is there any way we can send the file as well as some other datatype as a response in a single request?

I tried with response.json by sending the metadata, as well as audio data (converting bytes to string), but while converting to string, I feel, some of the metadata of the audio is lost.

Would like to know, is there any effective way to send files, as well as some other metadata using Sanic in a single request?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can do like what you said by converting the bytes, but that may not be so efficient. Usually you would want to stream a large file like audio. You could send the meta data first, followed by the audio bytes. Of course, this all supposes that whatever will be calling this endpoint knows how to decipher the response.

Comment: I just tried to do a little hack...
I send the metadata in header and stream the file as usual (response.file())

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to do a little hack... I send the metadata in the header and stream the file as usual (response.file()), so from the client side, I read the metadata from the header, and get the file as resp

example:

```
        headers = {
            'metadata': text,
        }

        return await response.file(audio_file, headers=headers)
```